# Unique constraint violated when I have a non-unique index

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint, unique-index

In my data warehouse I have table with unique key `TABLE_UK` on columns `(ID,IDATE,NAME,GENERATION,O_ID,NODE_ID)` and a non-unique index `PER_INDEX` on columns `(ID,NAME,GENERATION,STRUCTURE_AREA,O_ID)`.

While loading data from a source table I am receiving an error:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (PER_INDEX) violated

I checked the unique columns but there are no duplicates.

Why I am getting this unique constraint violation error on a non-unique index?

Also in order to load data into target table do I need to drop this index or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Can you please post the complete DDL of your table, or at least a describe of `PER_INDEX`?

Comment: You can have a unique constraint backed by a non-unique index. What do `user_indexes` and `user_constraints` show for your table?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a unique constraint which is backed up by a non-unique index, if you create the index first:

```
create table t42 (id number);

Table T42 created.

create index per_index on t42(id);

Index PER_INDEX created.

alter table t42 add constraint per_unique unique (id);

Table T42 altered.

select index_name, uniqueness
from user_indexes where table_name = 'T42';

INDEX_NAME                     UNIQUENES
------------------------------ ---------
PER_INDEX                      NONUNIQUE

select constraint_name, constraint_type, status, deferrable, index_name
from user_constraints where table_name = 'T42';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS   DEFERRABLE     INDEX_NAME                   
------------------------------ - -------- -------------- ------------------------------
PER_UNIQUE                     U ENABLED  NOT DEFERRABLE PER_INDEX
```

Given the name it seems likely it was added as an index first and then a constraint was put on top later.

One reason to do this in two steps is if you know there is existing data that is not unique, but you want all new data to be unique; then you can create a non-unique index, and add the constraint with the `novalidate` clause:

```
alter table t42 add constraint per_unique unique (id) novalidate;
```

When a new row is added the non-unique index can still be used to quickly check if there is already a matching entry, and the constraint can throw an exception if there is. For that check it doesn't really matter if the index is unique. The only real difference is the check may get more then one existing match, but the constraint just cares that it's non-zero.

Oracle will also create a non-unique index automatically if you make the unique constraint deferrable; with a unique index an exception would be thrown immediately as that check can't be deferred:

```
create table t42 (id number);

Table T42 created.

alter table t42 add constraint per_unique unique (id) deferrable;

Table T42 altered.

select index_name, uniqueness
from user_indexes where table_name = 'T42';

INDEX_NAME                     UNIQUENES
------------------------------ ---------
PER_UNIQUE                     NONUNIQUE

select constraint_name, constraint_type, status, deferrable, index_name
from user_constraints where table_name = 'T42';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                C STATUS   DEFERRABLE     INDEX_NAME                   
------------------------------ - -------- -------------- ------------------------------
PER_UNIQUE                     U ENABLED  DEFERRABLE     PER_UNIQUE
```

Note that the constraint doesn't have to have the same name as the index if you create them in two steps - when you add the constraint it will use any index which matches the columns the constraint is against. When the index is created automatically then the constraint and index have the same name.

---

You can't load data that violates that constraint unless you remove it, but as it's presumably there for a reason it isn't something to do lightly. You need to understand why the constraint exists, and why your data violates it - one of them may be wrong but we can't really help you decide which. That's a business decision as well as a technical one.

Comment: so u mean a nonunique index can act as unique constraint for table? Index 'PER_INDEX' has uniqueness as nonunique and is of type normal.

Comment: @priya77 - the constraint uses the non-unique index, yes; I'm not sure quite what it does under the hood, but I suppose it can quickly use the index to see if there is already a value that violates the constraint. For that purpose it doesn't really matter if the index is itself unique.

Comment: My index was created for performance purpose..I checked in the source table as follows:  
Select count(*),ID,NAME,GENERATION,STRUCTURE_AREA,O_ID from target_table group by ID,NAME,GENERATION,STRUCTURE_AREA,O_ID having count(*)>1;
This query returns

Comment: @priya77 - indexes usually are. That doesn't tell you why the unique constraint was added on top of the index. Check that constraints you have. Also might be interesting to look in `user_objects` and compare the `created` time for the index and the constraint. And the query from your last comment is only looking at the source table, not the destination - the error is coming when you add the source rows to the destination. You may have no duplicates in either separately.

Comment: the problem is I cannot compare both of them together as the data is in huge number in both tables..many times the SQL developer gets hanged whenever I Try to run query compairing both of them..hence wanted to find some other way to fix the iisue